# PowerShell Job Queue

Tags: powershell, queue, start-job

Run a job for each server in a list. I only want 5 jobs running at a time. When a job completes, it should start a new job on the next server on the list.  Here's what I have so far, but I can't get it to start a new job after the first 5 jobs have ran:

```
   $MaxJobs = 5
   $list = Get-Content ".\list.csv"
   $Queue = New-Object System.Collections.Queue
   $CurrentJobQueue = Get-Job -State Running
   $JobQueueCount = $CurrentJobQueue.count

   ForEach($Item in $list)
  {
  Write-Host "Adding $Item to queue"
  $Queue.Enqueue($Item)
  }

 Function Global:Remote-Install
 {
 $Server = $queue.Dequeue()
 $j = Start-Job -Name $Server -ScriptBlock{

        If($JobQueueCount -gt 0)
        {
        Test-Connection $Server -Count 15
        }##EndIf
    }##EndScriptBlock

  }

For($i = 0 ;$i -lt $MaxJobs; $i++) 
{
Remote-Install
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing... I think this is going to work out for me..   
$list = Get-Content ".\list.csv"
$queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::Synchronized((New-Object System.Collections.Queue))

ForEach($Item in $list)
{
Write-Host "Adding $Item to queue"
$Queue.Enqueue($Item)
}
$Server = $queue.Dequeue()

foreach ($server in $list){
   
    $running =  Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.JobStateInfo.State -eq 'Running' }
    
    if ($running.Count -le 2)
    {
    .. Script here ..
    } 
    else
    {
    $running | Wait-Job
    }
        
}

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell will do this for you if you use `Invoke-Command` e.g.:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverArray -ScriptBlock { .. script here ..} -ThrottleLimit 5 -AsJob
```

BTW I don't think your use of a .NET Queue is going to work because Start-Job fires up another PowerShell process to execute the job.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The thing about Invoke-Command is that it wants you to invoke the command on another computer.

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at the cmdlet `Split-Pipeline` of the module [SplitPipeline](https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline).
The code will look like:

```
Import-Module SplitPipeline
$MaxJobs = 5
$list = Get-Content ".\list.csv"
$list | Split-Pipeline -Count $MaxJobs -Load 1,1 {process{
    # process an item from $list represented by $_
    ...
}}
```

`-Count $MaxJobs` limits the number of parallel jobs. `-Load 1,1` tells to pipe
exactly 1 item to each job.

The advantage of this approach is that the code itself is invoked synchronously
and it outputs results from jobs as if all was invoked sequentially (even
output order can be preserved with the switch `Order`).

But this approach does not use remoting. The code works in the current PowerShell session in several runspaces.